# JMeter on startup returns multiple ERROR | Error filtering class org.bouncycastle.....information does not match

Tags: jmeter, bouncycastle

Every time I run JMeter I received multiple bouncycastle errors. I have checked I have the latest jar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default JMeter doesn't contain the "bouncycastle" .jar file, as per [Readme](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/README.md#requirements):

> Some jars are not included with JMeter. If required, these should be downloaded and placed in the lib directory
>
> - JDBC - available from the database supplier
> - JMS - available from the JMS provider
> - [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) - only needed for SMIME Assertion

Looking into [gradle.properties](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/gradle.properties#L59)

```
bouncycastle.version=1.67
```

So if you're using Bouncy Castle API somewhere i.e. in the [SMIME Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMIME_Assertion) (check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) for more details if needed) - make sure to have only one set of BC .jar files and preferably stick to version of 1.67 so JMeter implementation would match the API in .jars

If you don't use Bouncy Castle API just [download and install the latest stable version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi), it will not give you this error.